# RestTemplate returns data in String but not populate list nested objects

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a restTemplate trying to access data from a url and then map into a a object.
All the data comes but a certain nested list is not getting populated .
here is the code trying to call url.

```
    Resp rsp = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=**MY_API_KEY**&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=nature",Resp.class);
```

Here are my model classes .

```
 @XmlRootElement
public class Resp {
private String stat;
private Photos photos;
setters and getters
```

Photo and Photos are as follows

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlType
public class Photos {
private String total;
private String page;
private String pages;
private String perpage;
private List<Photo> photo;
setters and getters
```

Photo.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlType
public class Photo {
private String id;
private String isfamily;
private String title;
private String ispublic;
private String owner;
private String secret;
private String server;
private String isfriend;
setters and getters
```

the response I should get is :

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="2" pages="89" perpage="10" total="881">
<photo id="2636" owner="47058503995@N01" 
    secret="a123456" server="2" title="test_04"
    ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" />
<photo id="2635" owner="47058503995@N01"
    secret="b123456" server="2" title="test_03"
    ispublic="0" isfriend="1" isfamily="1" />
<photo id="2633" owner="47058503995@N01"
    secret="c123456" server="2" title="test_01"
    ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" />
<photo id="2610" owner="12037949754@N01"
    secret="d123456" server="2" title="00_tall"
    ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" />
</photos>
</rsp>
```

But i am getting everything except list of photos.

```
Resp [stat=ok, photos=Photos [total=420727, page=1, pages=4208, perpage=100, 
photo=]]
```

When i receive it in String i get all the data

```
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
 "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/? 
 api_key=**MY_API_KEY**&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=nature", 
 String.class);
```

this returns all the expected data but not into the list of photos.

Comment: try adding `@XmlElementWrapper` to `List<Photo> photo`

Comment: i tried , it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @JsonUnwrapped in your Photos class before the property Photo-
@JsonUnwrapped
private List photo;
Also use @JsonProperty before each member variable in your Photo class.

Comment: did it , same thing happens .