# JAXB Unmarshaller returning null in object after parsing from XML

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling, pojo

I have a String object with xml data in it .
I want that data in POJO , i tried using JAXB unmarshaller to convert but it always give me null values in the object attributes.

this is my code :

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=MY_API_KEY&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=nature", String.class);    
String resp = response.getBody();

JAXBContext jaxBcontext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Resp.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxBcontext.createUnmarshaller();
Resp respObj = (Resp)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(resp));
```

the value in String is :

```
 <rsp stat="ok">
 <photos page="1" pages="4226" perpage="100" total="422597">
 <photo id="28534349567" owner="79805131@N08" secret="b8bd7fe7cb" 
 server="843" farm="1" title="Savoie S006." ispublic="1" isfriend="0" 
 isfamily="0"/>
 <photo id="43355895332" owner="155237230@N05" secret="75fd48d040" 
 server="1769" farm="2" title="IMG_3139" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" 
 isfamily="0"/>
 <photo id="41595746070" owner="125407841@N08" secret="1f216ab8b8" 
 server="1822" farm="2" title="" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0"/>
 </photos>
 </rsp>
```

the POJOS are :

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlRootElement(name = "rsp")
 public class Resp {

    @XmlElement(name="stat")
    private String stat;

    @XmlElement(name="photos" , type = Photos.class)
    private Photos photos;

    public String getStat() {
        return stat;
    }
    //constructors and getter setters
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "photos")
public class Photos {

    @XmlElement(name="total")
    private String total;

    @XmlElement(name="page")
    private String page;

    @XmlElement(name="pages")
    private String pages;

    @XmlElement(name="perpage")
    private String perpage;

    @XmlElement(name="photo" , type=Photo.class)
    private List<Photo> photoObject = new ArrayList<Photo>();

    // constructors and getter setters.
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "photo")
public class Photo {

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name="isfamily")
    private String isfamily;

    @XmlElement(name="title")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name="ispublic")
    private String ispublic;

    @XmlElement(name="owner")
    private String owner;

    @XmlElement(name="secret")
    private String secret;

    @XmlElement(name="server")
    private String server;

    @XmlElement(name="isfriend")
    private String isfriend;

    // constructors and setter getter
```

the response i get is null values in all these objects.

Resp [stat=null, photos=Photos [total=null, page=null, pages=null, 
   perpage=null, photo=]]

the value in String which i get is absolutely correct , but when i try to map my data to a POJO it starts giving error.

Other approach I used it to get the data directly in the object , like I have mentioned in my other question , but it also have some issues in that.

[RestTemplate returns data in String but not populate list nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337480/resttemplate-returns-data-in-string-but-not-populate-list-nested-objects)

if anyone can help in either one of these that'd be helpful.

Comment: ``stat`` is not an ``XmlElement`` but an ``XmlAttribute`` (the same for ``total``, ``page`` etc). ``photos`` is not an ``XmlRootElement``.

Answer (score 0):

As @f1sh already already commented,
your problems are caused by several issues within your POJO classes

- In your XML response you have
  `<rsp stat="ok">...</rsp>` (i.e. `stat`is an XML attribute)
  instead of `<rsp><stat>ok</stat>...</rsp>` (`stat`being an XML element).
  Therefore, in your `Resp` class the `stat`property needs to annotated with 
  `@XmlAttribute` instead of `@XmlElement`.
- For the same reason, in your `Photos` class, all properties
  except for the `photoObject`property need to be annotated with
  `@XmlAttribute` instead of `@XmlElement`.
- For the same reason, in your `Photo` class all properties
  need to be annotated with `@XmlAttribute` instead of `@XmlElement`.

Some more best practices to consider:

- In your `Photos` and `Photo` classes you can remove the `@XmlRootElement` annotation
  because theses are not root elements.
  Only the `Resp` class is a root element and therefore needs `@XmlRootElement`.
- In your `Photos` class you should rename the `photoObject` property to `photoObjects`
  (with a plural **s**) because it is a list. This would make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .

The annotations @XMLAttribute and @XmlElements needed to be put on setters .

Did not work for getters and declarations.